# Cannot find module @ionic/angular (ionic 4) from test-file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jestjs

I'm trying to use jest to test an Ionic app. My jest configuration is:

```
preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts',
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@ngrx|@ionic-native|@ionic)'],
globals: {
  __TRANSFORM_HTML__: true,
},
```

The `setupJest.js` file has `import 'jest-preset-angular';`.

I have a very simple test where I use TestBed to create an instance of the App component and check that it's truthy. In this code I have `import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';`.

Jest errors with:

> `Cannot find module '@ionic/angular' from 'app.component.test.ts'`

If I just remove the `import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular'` from the test file, Jest gives me the same error from the component file:

> `Cannot find module '@ionic/angular' from 'app.component.ts'`

Using `ionic serve` / building works, jest is just giving me this error that it can't import X from Y.

How can I get jest to import from `@ionic` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this from the information in the linked GitHub issue. I arrived at the final configurations linked here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15695#issuecomment-428412641

Since, I have modified these configurations to speed up the tests (with cache) and still have not run into issues. My current configurations:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    // jest-preset-angular sets ts-jest tsConfigFile as "src/tsconfig.spec.json". This overwrites
    // it to use the default `tsconfig.json`. You can change this to your preferred config.
    __TRANSFORM_HTML__: true,
  },
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@ionic/core/loader': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/esm/es5/ionic.define.js',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@ionic)',
  ],
};
```

`src/setupJest.ts` only includes `import 'jest-preset-angular'`.

TypeScript configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
  }
}
```

You can probably vary some of these configuration settings quite a bit, but the most important one is `allowJs`. This is *required* or else `jest` won't be able to import a lot of the Ionic libraries properly.

Finally, remember to import from `/ngx` with Ionic 4 files. For example:

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat or do
npm update
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.